# Unable to compile vdproj with devenv - 'targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86''

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, vdproj

I've been searching around the web for the past hours, finding a lot of information related to my problem - but none actually fixing them.

My machine is 64 bit with a 32 bit Visual Studio 10 installed. 
Solution uses .Net 4. 
Solution includes 64 bits installation of Crystal Reports. 
Solution also includes log4net.

Compilation of project in VS2010 is OK for both Debug and Release, any cpu.

I have added a Web Setup Project that I want to build. 
However, no matter the configuration I get the following errors when compiling (both within VS UI and command line using devenv.exe):

```
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'log4net.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'log4net.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
ERROR: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
WARNING: File 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll' targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
```

I have tried to explicitly set the configuration for the projects to both x86 and x64, without any change.

Can someone guide me on the right way?

Edit - added screenshot showing that I am unable to choose platform for the setup project.

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to mark the Setup project as a 64-bit installer.  Your Setup project's `TargetPlatform` property in the Properties window, change it from x86 (the default) to x64.
Also make sure you deploy the 64-bit version of log4net and that your C# project's `TargetPlatform` setting is Any CPU.
And make sure that you actually *need* your app to run as a 64-bit process, that's rare.

Comment: I am unable to do so. See attached screenshot.

Comment: Properties window, not the Project + Properties dialog.  Use View + Properties Window if necessary.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh... 
Build: 13 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped

Answer (score 26):

1. Open Deployment.vdproj, in Notepad.
2. Find string "TargetPlatform" = "3:0"
3. Change to "TargetPlatform" = "3:1" for AMD64, or "TargetPlatform" = "3:2" for Itanium.
4. Save Deployment.vdproj.
   In Visual Studio you don't see any changes, but your Project now AMD64.

Comment: Worked for me too, magic! Thanks! I don't know why Microsoft was not notified about the importance of this simple and basic action...

Comment: I don't know why such a way. Is that a bug ?. ok but it worked. Thanks

Comment: Or click install project and there in properties change `TargetPlatform` to x64.

Answer (score 10):

1. Go to Visual Studio "View" menu and click Properties Windows:

[image]

2. Select Target Framework x64 bit:

[image]

Comment: This solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

1. Open a deployment project.
2. In the Solution Explorer, select the deployment project.
3. In the Properties window, select the TargetPlatform property.
4. Choose either Itanium for an Intel Itanium 64-bit platform, or x64 for any other 64-bit platform (such as AMD64 and EM64T instruction sets).
5. At installation time, an error will be raised and installation will be halted if the target computer is not compatible with the specified platform.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the **TargetPlatform**.

select the setup project > properties and change the `TargetPlatform` to `x64`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a deployment project.
2. In the Solution Explorer, select the deployment project.
3. In the Properties window, select the TargetPlatform property.
4. Choose either Itanium for an Intel Itanium 64-bit platform, or x64 for any other 64-bit platform (such as AMD64 and EM64T instruction sets).

At installation time, an error will be raised and installation will be halted if the target computer is not compatible with the specified platform.

Answer (score 0):

You may need an x64 Windows Service installed (think powershell) that needs to communicate to an x86 application. Your answer (properties/TargetPlatform) got me over that hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Visual Studio 2010

Go to your Project > Right Click and select `Properties`.

Under Compile, go to `Advanced Compile Options`

Locate `Target CPU`, then either

select `x86` for `32bit systems`, `x64` for `64bit systems` or `Any CPU`

Answer (score 0):

My .net 2010 Projects all include an x86 and an x64 Setup Project.  The TargetPlatform for my Projects is Any CPU and each Setup Project has the correct - CPU Specific - TargetPlatform.  All this is part of a "baseline" .Net Project that I "clone" (copy then edit several files with NOTEPAD) into a new Project when I start development.  Has worked great for years.

I encountered this error in a new project and found no fix until I did the following:

```
- Open Project Properties >> Compile >> Advanced and set Target to x86
- "Build" x86 Setup Project
    - Build Success
- Changed Project Properties >> Compile >> Advanced Target to x64
- "Build" x64 Setup Project
    - Build Success
- Changed Project Properties >> Compile >> Advanced Target to Any CPU
- Build x86 Setup Project
    - Build Success
- Build x64 Setup Project
    - Build Success
```

Changing the Project Properties >> Compile >> Advanced to something other than Any CPU and back again seems to have turned the trick........