# Microsoft .NET Framework missing during making exe setup file form project

Tags: c#

During making setup file i am getting these errors i think all problem is due to missing of .net Framework in dependencies folder

[image]

Comment: what errors are you getting. Could help..

Comment: Sir i am adding screenshot but don't know why it not appearing only links are appearing

Comment: Please click on the link you will see the errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to compile vdproj with devenv - 'targeting 'x64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956601/unable-to-compile-vdproj-with-devenv-targeting-x64-is-not-compatible-with-t)
And also do mention 'What did you try?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your .net framework. Its with your version of log4net. The version you have included is exclusive to x64 systems while you are trying to make a installer that works with x86 systems.

Either switch your project architecture to x64 (you can do this in the build properties of your project file). Or find a version of log4net that allows for x86 execution.